# Flutter: How to get data in Firestore and show those data in a dropdownbutton?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem getting my data from Firestore and putting that data in a dropdown button. I want to get all of the entries with "Name of Organization" in my Firestore database and put them in a dropdown button.

My code:

```
child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    elevation: 5,
                    hint: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Choose type of Organization",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    items: typesOfOrg.map((String dropDownString){
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: dropDownString,
                        child: Text(dropDownString),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _value = value;
                        print(value);
                      });
                    },
                    value: _value,
                  ),
```

As of now, I have this dropdown button that creates "typesofOrg" as a static array.

```
var typesOfOrg = ["Breast Cancer", "DSWD"];
```

And in my database I have this structure:

[image]

Comment: and whats exactly the error?

Comment: There is no error sir marc, I just want to get the data in my firestore and put it in the dropdownbutton.

Comment: but you have posted code and most likely try to run it right? So in case the dropbox is not populated, there must be an error right?

Comment: The data in my code is just static sir marc, So now I wanna try to get the data in my database and put it in the dropdownbutton. and that's the thing I dont know how to do :(